# how to read URI fragment (i#d_token=)

Tags: angular

I'm getting id_token in the URI fragment as

```
https://localhost:5011/api/v1/signup-callback#id_token=eyJhb...
```

In the `app-routing.module.ts` routes are defined

```
const routes: Routes = [
  //...
  { path: 'api/v1/signup-callback', component: UserSignupCallbackComponent }
];
```

and the actual component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-signup-callback',
  templateUrl: './user-signup-callback.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-signup-callback.component.css']
})
export class UserSignupCallbackComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Initiated UserSignupCallbackComponent!');
  }

  constructor(
  ){}

}
```

Browser redirects to the  `https://localhost:5011/api/v1/signup-callback#id_token=eyJhb...` but my console log never gets logged.

How to read this #id_token from the fragment uri?

Answer (score 1):

In your `UserSignupCallbackComponent` you can do the following

```
  idToken: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(fragment);
      this.idToken = params.get('id_token');
      console.log(this.idToken);
    });
```